# How do I use an address stored in a cell within a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use IMPORTRANGE dynamically. I want to be able to list the range to pull from the target file in a cell, but I am not sure how to do this within the IMPORTRANGE function.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hoVFXyI_aPog825JTAJdEFEYSndi1fK-eN85OmVyuEE/edit#gid=0)

I would prefer to use a formula instead of a script to accomplish this.

I've experimented with INDIRECT, but this doesn't seem to be what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=importrange("SHEET_ID", indirect("B1"))
```

[image]

Comment: I added quotes around B1. It now pulls the first cell's value ("Blue"), but not the rest of the range. Is there another change to my formula that I'm missing? How did you get all the other colors to appear in your screenshot?

Comment: You source sheet only has data in 5 cells `A1:E1`; so I kinda used that for reference purpose. If you are using `A1:A5` its obviously pulling in 5 cells showcasing only one cell with data (blue) + 4 blank cells...

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. I meant for the range in cell B1 to be A1:E1. Thanks for clarifying. So simply adding quotes around the cell reference inside the INDIRECT function solved my problem. Thank you!